# Solve $e^{ina}=-1$

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

> Solve the following equation:
>   $$e^{ina}=-1 \quad a\in\mathbb{R},\ n \in \mathbb{N}^{*}$$

**My thoughts:**

\begin{align*}
e^{ina}&=-1\\
&=e^{i\pi} \\
\iff na&=\pi [2\pi] \\
\end{align*}
but why they wrote: 
$$na\equiv n\pi [2\pi] $$
[image]

Comment: It seems to me that they are capturing both the situations for your e-power to be equal to $-1$ as well as $1$! Since $n$ is positive integer, this way all multiples of $\pi$ are now captured.

Comment: The book is correct; remember it's saying $-1$ is a root of $P_n(z)$, not that $-1$ works to plug into $w$. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

My French is mediocre, however, the book is correct. It is saying that $-1$ is a root of the polynomial $P_n$ if and only if $na \equiv n\pi \; [2\pi]$. This is true because
\begin{align*}
-1 \text{ is a root of } P_n(z)
&\iff w = (-1)^n \text{ satisfies } w^2 - 2 \cos(na) z + 1 \\
&\iff \text{For } w = (-1)^n = e^{in\pi}, w = e^{ina} \text{ or } w = e^{-ina}\\
&\iff e^{in\pi} = e^{ina} \text{ or } e^{in\pi} = e^{-ina} \\
&\iff na \equiv n\pi \;[2\pi] \text{ or } na \equiv -n\pi \;[2\pi]
\end{align*}
But now, $n\pi \equiv -n\pi \; [2\pi]$. So the two conditions are the same, and we have
$$
-1 \text{ is a root of } P_n(z) \iff na \equiv n \pi \; [2\pi].
$$

Comment: +1 great explanation